# @ModelAttribute objects fields are not binding, and are null in the controller

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, modelattribute

I have a list of "BuyStocks" objects named "buyRequests", which I am iterating through using th:each and referencing using the name "Stock".

I also have a single "SellStocks" object names "soldStocks". Each "buyRequests" object property is being populated in the "soldStocks" fields and shown in the view with its own "Sell" button.

When I am clicking the "Sell" button, I want the populated fields to be saved in the "soldStocks" object and fetched through the '@ModelAttribute SellStock soldStocks' parameter in the controller "Post" function.

The problem is that in the controller, the "soldStocks" object properties is null.

[image: Screenshot of View]
(the fields will be hidden after I find a solution)

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{userEmail}/sell/{stockName}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String postSell(@PathVariable String userEmail ,@PathVariable String stockName,@ModelAttribute SellStocks soldStocks, ModelMap model)
```

View:

```html
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card border-dark mb-3" th:each="Stock : ${buyRequests}">
        <div th:if="${!Stock.id.userEmail.equals(userEmail)}">
            <div class="card-header" th:text="${'Stock Name: ' + Stock.id.stockName}"></div>
            <div class="card-body text-dark">
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" th:text="${'Buyer: '+ Stock.id.userEmail}"></h6>
                <h6 class="card-soubtitle mb-2 text-muted" th:text="${'Buying Price: ' + Stock.price}"></h6>
                <p class="card-text" th:text="${'Required Quantity: ' + Stock.quantity}"></p>

                <form class="text-center border border-light p-3 form-row"
                   th:object="${soldStocks}" th:action="${'/'+{userEmail}+'/sell/'+{Stock.id.stockName}}" method="post">

                    <input th:id="${soldStocks.price}" name="${soldStocks.price}" th:value="${Stock.price}" />
                    <input th:id="${soldStocks.quantity}" name="${soldStocks.quantity}" th:value="${Stock.quantity}" />
                    <input th:id="${soldStocks.id.userEmail}" name="${soldStocks.id.userEmail}" th:value="${Stock.id.userEmail}" />
                    <input th:id="${soldStocks.id.stockName}" name="${soldStocks.id.stockName}"  th:value="${Stock.id.stockName}" />

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary my-1">Sell</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The fields I am struggling with:

```
<input  th:id="${soldStocks.price}" name="${soldStocks.price}"  th:value="${Stock.price}"/>
<input  th:id="${soldStocks.quantity}" name="${soldStocks.quantity}" th:value="${Stock.quantity}"/>
<input  th:id="${soldStocks.id.userEmail}" name="${soldStocks.id.userEmail}" th:value="${Stock.id.userEmail}"/>
<input  th:id="${soldStocks.id.stockName}" name="${soldStocks.id.stockName}" th:value="${Stock.id.stockName}"/>
```

Comment: th:object is missing

Comment: You should be using `th:object` on the form tag and `th:field` on the input fields instead of `th:id`, `th:value` .

Answer (score 0):

Add th:object="${soldStocks}" in the form tag

Comment: hi Niraj Jha, thanks for the answer :) , i have tried that, but unfortunately, it didn't work,  i have edited my question, and added th:object=${soldStocks} to the form

Comment: remove all those and just check with the price and use th:field="*{price}" instead of th:id and remove the name and in the value hard code it with th:value="10"

Comment: This way just ensure that everything is correct except the mapping syntax

Comment: the reason i used th:id instead of th:field is that i need to get values from the 'Stock' object, and use them to populate the properties of 'soldStocks' object.  if i use th:field, the th:value is ignored, and the values that are populated, are those of the 'soldStocks' object instead of those of the 'Stock' object,